# JNI passing instance variables to functions referenced from other translation units

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface, sdl-2

I am having some trouble getting this sorted out.

I am doing some JNI stuff with SDL. The code is structured like this:

```
class.c
int Android_JNI_GetTouchDeviceIds(int **ids) {
    JNIEnv *env = Android_JNI_GetEnv();

    jint sources = 4098; /* == InputDevice.SOURCE_TOUCHSCREEN */
    jmethodID mid = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, mActivityClass, "inputGetInputDeviceIds", "(I)[I");
    jintArray array = (jintArray) (*env)->CallStaticObjectMethod(env, mActivityClass, mid, sources);
    int number = 0;
    *ids = NULL;
    if (array) {
        number = (int) (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, array);
        if (0 < number) {
            jint* elements = (*env)->GetIntArrayElements(env, array, NULL);
            if (elements) {
                int i;
                *ids = SDL_malloc(number * sizeof (**ids));
                for (i = 0; i < number; ++i) { /* not assuming sizeof (jint) == sizeof (int) */
                    (*ids)[i] = elements[i];
                }
                (*env)->ReleaseIntArrayElements(env, array, elements, JNI_ABORT);
            }
        }
        (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, array);
    }
    return number;
}

class.h
int Android_JNI_GetTouchDeviceIds(int **ids);
```

Now in another class

```
class2.h
int Android_JNI_GetTouchDeviceIds(int **ids);
class2.c
const int number = Android_JNI_GetTouchDeviceIds(&ids);
```

The glue code between C and Java is in class.c and I know how to pass the instance to that class from the java side.

The thing is I don't want to edit the class.c function signature but I was thinking that if I could somehow have this function:

```
int Android_JNI_GetTouchDeviceIds(int **ids)
```

get the instance variable so that instead of doing a static method lookup, I am not using a static global reference but make it use a non static instance instead.

How can I restructure this code to have **Android_JNI_GetTouchDeviceIds** use an instance variable to do the function calling?

Comment: Isn't this pretty much what you did over in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32669822/ ?

Comment: "How can I restructure this code to have Android_JNI_GetTouchDeviceIds use an instance variable"?  You need an object.  How can you restructure your code?  Get an object.